# Django: Create new user account

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble creating a new account and then logging in. I enter all the credentials in (first_name, last_name, username, password), and select "Create new account", and it successfully redirects me back to the login page. However, when I try to login with this new account, it says that my username doesn't exist.

The problem is most likely in my views.py file:

```
def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"], 
                        password = request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
        Student.objects.create(user=new_user, 
                               first_name=str(request.POST.get("first_name")),
                               last_name=str(request.POST.get("last_name")))
        new_user.is_active = True
        return redirect('../')
    else:
        return render(request, 'polls/create_account.html')
```

Let me know if you guys need any more code or information. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to save `new_user` again after you do `new_user.is_active = True`. You need to save any changes you made to a model instance. Although I doubt that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

The password field needs to be encrypted. If you are going to set the password, you need to use set_password() method that will deal with encryption.

```
        new_user = User(username = request.POST["username"])
        new_user.set_password(request.POST["password"])
        new_user.save()
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this another option if you work in `form` with `cleaned_data`:

```
def create_account(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = RegisterForm(request.POST) #registration form
        if form.is_valid():
            cd              = form.cleaned_data
            username        = cd['username']
            password        = cd['password']

            new_user = User.objects.create_user(
                            username = cd['username'],
                            password = cd['password']
                        )
            new_user.save()

            #... do stuff
```